# Geometry problem: two squares aligned as shown in image

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve this geometry problem. All my efforts so far have resulted in 4th grade equations which I can only solve numerically.

Two squares aligned as shown in the image. What is the length of x?

[image]

Comment: What equation did you get? Fourth-degree looks correct to me.

Comment: The obvious one is: y^2+x^2=10^2 where y = 10x/(10+x)

Comment: That is what I get as well, equivalently $x^4+20 x^3+100 x^2-2000 x-10000 = 0$. [Quartic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation) *can* be solved exactly, but it is not nice.

Comment: I think Dan has the right idea. If you set $y$ to be the height of the smaller triangle (on the right), you get
$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
x^2 + y^2 = 10^2 \\
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{10}{10+x}
\end{split}
\right.
$$

Comment: I saw this problem in an Instagram post a couple of months or so ago, I opened up the comments and saw a solution (which involved trig-functions, that's all I remember). I quickly closed it again not to spoil the fun solving it. But now I fail both at solving the problem AND finding that post again. :-(

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... I concur about your system, and about the 4th degree equation. As it happens, the quartic factors into a pair of nice quadratics ... provided you get clever with $\sqrt{2}$. (This is non-obvious. I only realized it by calculating the exact roots in *Mathematica*, seeing a bunch of $\sqrt{2}$s, and then re-factoring the over the corresponding "field extension".) Defining $s:=10$ (to help track how this parameter affects the outcome), we have $$x^4+ 2 s x^3+ s^2 x^2- 2 s^3 x -s^4 = ( (\sqrt2-1) x^2+sx+s^2) ( (\sqrt2+1) x^2 - sx - s^2)$$

Comment: Given Blue's comment, one could then hope for a direct path to $(\sqrt2+1)x^2-sx-s^2=0$. I have no idea if that's feasible

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Taking as unknown $t$ the upper vertical segment you have the equation
$$(\sqrt{100+t^2}+10)^2=10^2+\left(10+\sqrt{10^2-(10-t)^2}\right)^2$$ which gives the solution  $$t=5\left(1+\sqrt2-\sqrt{2\sqrt2-1}\right)$$
This way you have $$\boxed{x=\sqrt{10^2-(10-t)^2}}$$

Comment: Looks great- but it will take me some time to understand!

Comment: @DanByström: It is just Pythagoras's theorem.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how did you solve t out of the first equation?

Comment: It was the solution in closed form gives by Wolfram. However you can solve the equation of fourth degree if you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In picture $CE=x$, $AF=y$ and $CF=z$

$\triangle EFC\sim\triangle  EAC \Rightarrow \frac x{x+10}=\frac {10}{y+10}$

$\Rightarrow xy+10x=10x+100\Rightarrow xy =100$

$y^2=10^2+(10-z)^2=200-20z+z^2$

$x^2=10^2-z^2$

Multiplying both sides of these relations we get:

$(xy)^2=100=(10-z^2)(z^2-20z+200)$

Which is an equation of 4 degree in terms of z. Wolfram gives positive root as:

$z=5(1-\sqrt 2+\sqrt{2\sqrt 2 -1})\approx 4.7$

Hence the measure of x is:

$x=\sqrt{10^2-4.7^2}\approx 8.825$